# SVN doesn't work when execute the command 'sudo apachectl start'

Tags: eclipse, svn

I use **svn** in eclipse and when I execute the command `sudo apachectl start` the SVN doesn't work.

Error:

```
Location information has been specified incorrectly.

svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on 'svn/SAI'

keep location anyway?
```

I use Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Eclipse Helios and the connector of SVN is `SVNKit 1.7.6`.

Answer (score 0):

Both your apache server and the SVN are using the same port. Thats why once you start up apache you are not able to connect to SVN

Answer (score 0):

I removed Subversion e installed Subclipse. The error now is:

Error validating location: "org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA Layer request failed.